# is using the float data type in this scenario really necessary

Tags: android, floating-point

I am going through a circular custom view implementation(android) and I see the developer making alot of uses of the float data type. I for one has never used this because I haven't seen the need to. I am not sure why he's using it so I am wondering if there are any advantages to using it especially in this scenario where mainly coordinates are being stored and calculating will be done using them.

```
/** The radius of the inner circle */
private float innerRadius;

/** The radius of the outer circle */
private float outerRadius;

/** The circle's center X coordinate */
private float cx;

/** The circle's center Y coordinate */
private float cy;

/** The left bound for the circle RectF */
private float left;

/** The right bound for the circle RectF */
private float right;

/** The top bound for the circle RectF */
private float top;

/** The bottom bound for the circle RectF */
private float bottom;

/** The X coordinate for the top left corner of the marking drawable */
private float dx;

/** The Y coordinate for the top left corner of the marking drawable */
private float dy;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, performance-wise...http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#AvoidFloat

He may be trying to abstract screen coordinates, look at the actual assigned values of these variables, are they things like 0.0 and 720.0 or are they more like -1.0, 1.0, etc.? In some situations it would make more sense to use a local coordinate system than to define things in terms of pixel position on screen.

But if they are still referencing things that look like screen positions, there is no real advantage that I know of to using floats vs. ints.